# WP8 browser control showing an empty page only

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, webbrowser-control

I tried to load an html file from isolated storage on to webbrowser control in wp8 application. But it shows only an empty page.
i tried to open the same file in IE browser of my machine and i got an alert 
Internet explorer restricted this webpage from running scripts or Activex controls and an option AllowBloackedContent. If i press the allow button it renders the html page on IE browser. 
So what changes i have to apply to my WP8 browser control to load the html file from isolated storage.
My xaml is

```
   <phone:WebBrowser  IsScriptEnabled="True" Grid.Row="0"  x:Name="extrasBrowserControl">
    </phone:WebBrowser>
```

And in code i used

```
    Uri uri = new Uri(filepath, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
        IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        if (myIsolatedStorage.FileExists(uri.ToString()))
        {
            extrasBrowserControl.Source = uri;
            extrasBrowserControl.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
   }
```

I also try to read the contents of html file as a string and load using extrasBrowserControl.NavigateToString(..). But still i can see the string only on browser.
How can i fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to read the content of the file as a string and use the function .NavigateToString(yourString) of the webbrowser. If the document respects the Html format, it should work.

```
     using (IsolatedStorageFile isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("myHtmlFile.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, isoStore)))
            {
               string text = reader.ReadToEnd();
               extrasBrowserControl.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
               extrasBrowserControl.NavigateToString(text);

               reader.Close();
               reader.Dispose();
            }
            isoStore.Dispose();

        }
```

Comment: Didn't you forgot to dispose the `IsolatedStorageFileStream` instance?

Comment: Yes it shows the html contents as string only. Not rendering the UI on browser. Like i explained if i open the file in IE browser it ask for a permission then only it renders. Is any way to overcome that